# Yii2 - Submit form value by hyperlink

Tags: php, forms, yii2, submit

**I have a form displayed inside a detailView**

It is located in `'value'=>$form->field($model, 'dummy5'),`

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'options' => ['class' => 'detail1-galeria-view2'],
    'attributes' => [
        // cria um array com a fotografia, em que carrega a path no campo fieldName da bd
        [
            'attribute'=>'',
            //'value'=>$model->foto,
            'value'=>Html::a(Html::img(Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl() . "/" .$model->foto, ['width'=>'192', 'height' => "256"]), $model->foto),
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->nome,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->categoria,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->descricao,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->valor.' '.'€',
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value'=>$form->field($model, 'dummy5'),
        ],
        // info
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'format' => 'raw',
        // nesta hiperligação passo o valor do model->nome deste registo para encomendas/create
        //'value'=> Html::a(Yii::t('app','Comprar'), Url::toRoute(['encomendas/create', 'nome' => $model->nome, 'preco' => $model->valor])),
        'value' => Html::a('Submit', ['encomendas/create', 'nome' => $model->nome, 'preco' => $model->valor, 'qt' => $model->dummy5], ['data' => ['method' => 'post', 'params' => ['action' => 'produtos/view2']]]),
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

I need to submit the form value to the controller using `Html::a` or if not possible this way, trying with a submitButton that can pass all the other arguments (`'nome' => $model->nome, 'preco' => $model->valor`).

Why do i prefer `Html::a` to submit (if possible, instead of `Html::submitButton`), because i learn how to pass values via get to the controller, and with `Html::submitButton` i don't know if it can be done.

The downside of Html::a is that it doesn't validate my model, so nothing arrives to the controller in:

```
$qt = Yii::$app->request->get('qt');
```

**Photos from both detailView with form and next view where i want $qt coming from the other form and to be inserted has default value in this new form:**
[image]

[image]

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Hey @Andre. Now Where You Stuck Man ? What Happened ?

Comment: With you code what happen, error, wrong result, ...

Comment: Hello again @Nana. The issue is that i altered my project so that in my detailView a form is also rendered for the user to input quantity number of product items he needs to purchase. Then i pass the variable by get to the controller to use in a different controller later. The problem is that the button to render the new form belonging to other controller does not submits or validates the form and it's value. As result when i want to access the variable that represents the form ($qt) this variable is empty. This is happening because i'm using a Html::a element to render the next view.

Comment: I will edit the question with some photos. One for the detailView that renders the form and other for the next view where i want to pass the form value to the quantity field as value. Something like: <?= $form->field($model, 'quantidade')->textInput(['value' => $qt]) ?>

Comment: Hey @scaisEdge, your attempt to solution as disappeared. Did you delete it?

Comment: Yes i'm evaluating another solution..

Comment: @AndréCastro Just a question why you don't use a not db attribute field in your model for passign the quantity and use a fictional form->qt?. I think if you add to you model (not to the db) only to the model a proper field you extend you model for this situations.

Comment: That would be a perfect solution. For implementation in could use something like: public $dummy in my model. But how could i associate this $dummy var to the form and then when Html::a is activated the $dummy passes it's value to the controller?

Comment: I'm trying to create a fictional form. I created in Produtos model the var public $qt1, then in my detailView -> 'value'=>$form->field($model, 'qt1'), and then passed to the controller in Html::a like 'qt' =>$model->qt1. But it doesn't work. The value of $qt1 don't arrive to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem may be a mixture of `POST` and `GET` variables. Your `Html::a` link is not a submit button, and won't collect data from the form. As your models attribute `qt1` is empty for the model, no data is being submitted for the link.

To get around this you need to combine `GET` and `POST` requests, something like this;

```
'format' => 'raw',
'value' => Html::submit('Submit')
```

This will now pick up and submit via a `post` request, and form data that the user has added.

You will need to change the `action` parameter for the form. This is where you can create the `GET` parameters for the submission;

Where you create your form, do it like this;

```
 $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'action' => Url::to(['encomendas/create', 'nome' => $model->nome, 'preco' => $model->valor])
                ]);
```

And your filed should be

```
'attribute'=>'',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value'=>$form->field($model, 'qt'),
        ],
```

Now, in your action `encomadas/create` you will have access to the following variables:

Via the `GET` request - `nome` and `preco`.

Via the `POST` request - `qt1`

You can now use these as appropriate in your action and views.

Comment: Good afternoon... With $qt1 = Yii::$app->request->post('qt'); in my encomendas/create action still not able to access the form data that i want. qt1 is always empty :(

Comment: It's becaue the form field is being generated for the dummy5 property. Change is to qt, and it should work. I've amended my answer

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work also. In my model i have public $qt; declared. This one is hard :(

Comment: Ah, is `qt` a field in your database? What is the name of the field you are storing the quantity ordered in? What is the name of the model? I think the `post` value should be 'post(['modelName']['qt1'])'. Can you see what is in the post request for your controller? you should be able to find the value that the form is submitting, and rename your query accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
Html::a('Link Name', ['url/to'], ['data' => [
                                                'method' => 'post',
                                                'params' => ['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id],
                                            ], 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
```